# Integrability of infite sum of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of Lebesgue integrable functions in $\mathbb{R}$
Is it true that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ $=f(x)$ is also a Lebesgue integrable function?
If not, can you give me a counterexample?

First thought: Let $g_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} f_k$. Can we use that $g_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise a.e.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample: $f_n(x)=\mathbf{1}_{(n-1,n]}(x)$, $f_1(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$. Then $\int f_n d\lambda=1,\forall n$ but $f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ and $\int fd\lambda =\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! However, if f was Lebesgue integrable, can we prove that f_n is Lebesque integrable for every n $\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Let $f_1(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}(x),f_2(x)=-\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}(x),f_n=0,\forall n>2$. Then $f=0$, and so $\int f d\lambda =0$, but $f_1,f_2$ are not integrable. @MarsPi

Comment: @MarsPi https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577843/prove-that-the-series-sum-limits-n-infty-inftyfxn-converges-absolu?noredirect=1